# Obter post de uma unica categoria com have_posts() WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou mostrando os ultimos post de um blog em um site externo que estou desenvolvendo fora do wordpress.

```
<?php
    //Include WordPress
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('./blog/wp-load.php');
    //Define quantos posts serão exibidos
    query_posts('showposts=3');
?>
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>                      
    <span><?php the_time("d/m/Y"); ?></span>
    <?php the_category_ID(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <div>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">&laquo; Leia Mais...</a>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

A questão é que o blog esta separado em duas categorias e eu gostaria de exibir apenas uma delas.

link onde consegui essas funções.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde a versão 4.7 do WordPress não é mais preciso carregar o WordPress dessa maneira para buscar conteúdo, basta usar a REST API nativa:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3&categories={ID_DA_CATEGORIA}',
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$posts = json_decode( $resp, true );
curl_close($curl);

foreach( $posts as $post ) : ?>
    <li>
        <h4><?php echo $post['title']['rendered']; ?></h4>
        <span><?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime( $post['date'] ) ); ?></span>
        <?php // {ID_DA_CATEGORIA} ?>
        <?php echo $post['content']['rendered']; ?>
        <div>
            <a href="<?php echo $post['link']; ?>">&laquo; Leia Mais...</a>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Agora `$posts` é um array associativo com as informações dos últimos 3 posts da categoria que você pediu. Nesse array estão todas as informações que estão sendo pedidas ali no markup como título, link, data, etc.

Exemplo de objeto retornado:

```
{
    "id": 173,
    "date": "2017-07-25T01:35:08",
    "date_gmt": "2017-07-25T01:35:08",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "http://example.com//?p=173"
    },
    "modified": "2017-08-04T13:15:31",
    "modified_gmt": "2017-08-04T13:15:31",
    "slug": "resource-31",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "http://example.com/resource-31/",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Resource 31"
    },
    "content": {
        "rendered": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tellus lorem, aliquet ac est ac, convallis luctus nunc. Aliquam vitae mi ullamcorper elit vulputate gravida a nec turpis. Cras turpis ipsum, pretium in molestie in, facilisis eget elit. Phasellus semper dolor eu velit tempor, id interdum mi cursus. Mauris et leo in quam commodo rhoncus. Aliquam a erat iaculis, dignissim est eget, rutrum justo. Phasellus vel orci id risus maximus pellentesque ac nec sapien. Etiam sed commodo erat, in suscipit magna. Nullam accumsan nisl ex, sit amet malesuada enim luctus sed.</p>\n",
        "protected": false
    },
    "excerpt": {
        "rendered": "<p>In ornare ante lectus, nec mollis mi cursus non. Mauris risus ante, tincidunt sit amet euismod eget, congue non est. Nam vitae vulputate leo. Vivamus fringilla nulla ut nisl ornare pulvinar. Aliquam imperdiet pellentesque risus.</p>\n",
        "protected": false
    },
    "author": 12,
    "featured_media": 0,
    "comment_status": "open",
    "ping_status": "open",
    "sticky": false,
    "template": "",
    "format": "standard",
    "meta": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/173"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
            }
        ],
        "about": [
            {
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
            }
        ],
        "author": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/12"
            }
        ],
        "replies": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=173"
            }
        ],
        "version-history": [
            {
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/173/revisions"
            }
        ],
        "wp:attachment": [
            {
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=173"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621495/get-post-from-a-single-category-with-have-posts-wordpress

Comment: ok, alguém no SOen te deu essa resposta. Ela continua sendo errada porque faz 2 coisas que não devem ser feitas: carregar todo o WP via `wp-load.php` pra buscar posts e usar `query_posts`.

Comment: Entendi você esta certo, mas preciso entender a questão para resolver lá no SOen tbm.

Comment: E eu não to entendendo essa sua resposta, desenvolvo em front-end e usou pouquissimo php...

Comment: `$posts` é uma array que retorna todos esses valores do post certo? e com essa variavel que eu trabalho pra obter os dados do post? pq na verdade eu preciso apenas do titulo do post e da imagem que vem dentro do post, o texto eu quero ignorar.

Comment: editei pra inserir um exemplo completo buscando as mesmas informações que estavam no seu html

Comment: Obrigado @Ricardo, ficou mais claro. Mas ainda não funcionou.. recebi o seguinte erro.. acredito que seja o argumento do foreach.. 
_Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()_

Comment: Esse erro diz que `$posts` não é um array. Tem que conferir a sua chamada pra saber se a resposta está correta. Dê um `var_dump( $resp )` pra ver o que ta sendo retornado. Eu testei esse código aqui e funcionou.

Comment: testei o `var_dump( $resp )` mas a pagina da erro e perde todo o css, onde incluo no codigo para ver o que esta retornando?

Comment: mesmo a pagina perdendo o css e ficando desconfigurada ele me retornou `string(1270) "`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63666/discussion-between-bruno-cabral-and-ricardo-moraleida).